# jquery function when clicking on div but not its nested div

Tags: jquery, css

I am in dire need of your assistance yet again.

So basically i have a div, id="parent", which i want to be able to hide along with its contents, I've also nested a div inside this div, with an id of "nested". "Parent" is wider than "nested" so what I want to happen is that when you click on "parent" i want the hide function to activate, but if you click on "nested" this hide function doesn't activate.

However what is happening is that the function activates when you click on "parent" and when you click on "nested". Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="nested">
        <p>Contents</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JQUERY: (put a console.log there to represent the hide function)

```
var parent = $('#parent');
var nested = $('#nested');

parent.not(nested).click(function(){
    console.log('Click');
});
```

It seems like it should be simple but I cant figure it out! Are my selectors wrong? Is this something JQuery simply can't do?? Any help much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Events always bubble up. So if you click on the nested div it will bubble up that click event to the parent.

If I understood you correctly you only want to execute the click event when the parent was clicked and not the nested div itself.

Just validate that the current event was infact triggered by the parent and only then execute the code.

**EDIT**
Updated to use [**event.target**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) instead, as apparently `event.srcElement` is not cross-browser compatible.

```
var parent = $('#parent');

parent.click(function(event){
    if(event.target === this){
      console.log("parent was clicked and we execute actions...");
    }
    else{
        console.log("something else within parent was clicked and is ingored...");
    }
});​
```

​

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/5vJsB/)

> I would not recommend attaching click events to every single div you
> want to ignore. That is way to much maintenance and very error prone when eventually actions are required on the nested divs.

Comment: Thanks for the demo man, however i've tried using this code and it doesn't consle.log anything.

Comment: @bestfriendsforever: I had used the wrong property originaly, `srcElement` is the object containing the reference to the element which triggered the click event.

Comment: @bestfriendsforever`: Sorry, I even further improved the code. srcElement apparently does not work cross-browser. `event.target` should. http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: OK! cool this seems to work in jsfiddle! i'll pop it in my code! thanks man!

Comment: @bestfriendsforever`: If you get issues with `event.target` on some browsers, you can use it then in combination with event.srcElement. This can be combined into a single line of code similar to this: `var eventTarget = event.srcElement || event.target;` that should set `eventTarget` in either browser in case you have issues with just using event.target.

Comment: YES! this works! If only i understood more js. Thanks François!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$('#nested').click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: I want the function to activate when clicking on #parent, not #nested. meaning i want the "bubbling" to not go down the Dom tree(if i understand correctly), all other describes the bubbling to go up the dom tree. Not quite sure how this works

Comment: This won't work on IE8. Use `e.cancelBubble = true;` as well for it to work.

Comment: @bestfriendsforever That's what `.stopPropagation()` does -- it prevents the event from going "down".

Comment: @bestfriendsforever  what i mean is add the above, and then also add whatever you want to happen only on parent in the parent click event.  Then the clicks on nested wont trigger parent clicks.

Comment: @Abody97: Personally I'm not a big fan of attaching events purely for the sake of preventing bubbling up of an event. One can verify the source of the click event by looking at [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and only execute actions in the parent click event itself if it was triggered by itself.